# extend a column by location in a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to extend a column , but I don't know the column names in my original data so I want to access it by location and  extend it.
I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]
c=[a,b]
c=pd.DataFrame(c)

c[0].extend(['']*len(a))
print(c)
```

I want to create empty space in column location 0. So I get the following:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2
3
```

In my original code it is done in a loop, that is why I use the location not just `c.extend()`

I get the following error: `'Series' object has no attribute 'extend'`

Comment: Can you provide an example of what output you are expecting? I did not find the `extend` method in the documentation of pandas.

Comment: Do you want [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) ..? `c.append(pd.Series(['']*len(a), name=c.index.max()+1))`

Comment: No, I want to extend the column, with empty spaces as seen above for the specific column.

Comment: Try `c.reindex(np.arange(len(c)+len(a)), fill_value='')`

Comment: did you assign it back...? `c = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `fill_value` parameter set to `''`:

```
import numpy as np

a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]
c=[a,b]
c=pd.DataFrame(c)

c = c.reindex(np.arange(len(c)+len(a)), fill_value='')
```

[out]

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2         
3         
4
```